# Calling variables from other modules with Require JS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've been experimenting with RequireJS to try help organise my code. I just have a quick question regarding how I would be able to call certain variables from another script file.

My main script is structured like this:

```
require([
'game',
'piece',
], function(
Game,
Piece,
) {

var game = new Game();
var piece = new Piece();

game.start();
piece.start();

});
```

I am wanting to call the gridArray variable from my game.js script inside of my peice.js script.

I did try doing this but it returned undefined inside of the console

```
define([
'game'
], function(
Game
) {

function Piece(piece_type, current_row, current_col, current_status)
{
    this.piece_type = piece_type;
    this.current_row = current_row;
    this.current_col = current_col;
    this.current_status = current_status;
}

Piece.prototype.start = function()
{
    this.king();
    console.log(Game.gridArray)
}

Piece.prototype.king = function()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("chessBoard")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.fillRect(12.5, 12.5, 50, 50)
}

return Piece;
});
```

gridArray is called in game.js in this function

```
function Game()
{
    this.canvas;
    this.ctx;

    this.row = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
    this.gridArray = [];
}
```

Comment: You imported the `Game` function, not the `game` instance. `gridArray` is a member variable, not a static variable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the response,  I am not sure, I'm still quite a novice when it comes to coding, and have no clue how to incorporate this into my script. Any further help is appreciated